# NodeMCU Lua Amica v2 DeepSleep function

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

how can i put the NodeMCU Lua Amica v2 into deepSleep mode?
I read in much posts that it is just ESP.deepSleep() but in my case it doesn't work. 
Because I want to make a simple weather station with humidity and temperature and the NodeMCU sends the data to Ubidots every hour and in the rest of the time I want it to be in deepSleep mode for better battery life, because I only use a powerbank.

Thanks for answers

Comment: have you connected the pin RST with the pin D0 (or GPIO16 on some modules)? and what is the args  you send with ESP.deepSleep(...,...)??  it exist 3 modes to wake up the esp

Comment: I've connected the pin RST with D0 can you show me an example of the ESP.deepSleep()?

Comment: are you using wifi or not?

Comment: yes I'm using WiFi for sending the data

Answer (score 0):

dont forget when you wake up the esp, the code restart at beginning (write all your code in setup() and execute the ESP.deepSleep

the syntax of this function is (i suppose you are using the library)

```
ESP.deepsleep(duration, [wifi_state])

duration is in microsecond so duration = 1000000 * lapseInSecond

if you dont put wifi_state, is the default mode
if you put RF_DISABLED you dont use Wifi

 so 1 hour = 3600 * 1000000 microseconds   hope you could use int or long on 32 bits
```

Comment: So if i want wifi enabled i just make ESP.deepSleep(the 1 hour) ?

Comment: yes but i hope the number could be put in variable, dunno the type of variable accepted by the function  3600 * 1000000 is a long number

Comment: I think it will work otherwise I put the result of 3600 * 1000000 in the brackets

Comment: yes the max deep sleep interval appears to be ~71 minutes just read on book!!

Comment: on some esp module we have to use a 470 Ohm resistor between the 2 pins. Shorting the pins with a wire does not work (always)

Comment: @Frenchy the information in your book is outdated. This year the data type was changed to a 64-bit unsigned integer which allows deep sleep for up to ~3.5h. See all details in our blog post https://thingpulse.com/max-deep-sleep-for-esp8266/